# Angular 5 custom directive fires for element wrapped into *ngIf=false

Tags: angular, angular5, angular2-directives, angular-directive

I'm working on directive that should close dropdown after click outside. The element that has directive also has`*ngIf` and is not present on the page at the time of click, but directive is still firing the event - so the dropdown is never opened as `showList` becomes `false` immediatelly after `(click)="showList = true"` fired. How do I avoid this?

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4hqzwy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fclick-outside.directive.ts)

```js
import { Directive, HostListener, ElementRef, EventEmitter, Inject, PLATFORM_ID, Output, Input, OnInit, Renderer2, AfterContentInit } from '@angular/core';
import { isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';

@Directive({
  selector: '[clickOutside]'
})
export class ClickOutsideDirective implements AfterContentInit {

  ngAfterContentInit(): void {
    this.contentInitialized = true;
  }
  @Input("clickOutside") config: any = {};
  @Output() clickOutside: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  private isBrowser: boolean = false;
  private isIE11: boolean = false;
  private contentInitialized: boolean = false;

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2, private _el: ElementRef, @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: any) {
    this.isBrowser = isPlatformBrowser(platformId);
    this.isIE11 = this.isBrowser && !!(window as any).MSInputMethodContext && !!(document as any).documentMode;
  }

  @HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
  public onClick(event) {
    console.log("CLICKED");
    if (this.contentInitialized && !(this._el.nativeElement.contains(event.target) || (event.target == window.document.querySelector(this.config.excludeLocator)))) {
      this.clickOutside.emit(event);
    }
  }

  @HostListener('document:keyup', ['$event'])
  private onKeyup(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 27) {
      this.clickOutside.emit(event);
    }
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="menu-trigger" (click)="showList = true"></div>
<ul class="list" *ngIf="showList" (clickOutside)="showGiftList = false">
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li>item 3</li>
  <li>item 4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Your HTML doesn't use clickOutside anywhere. Post a complete minimal example, in a StackBlitz, reproducing the problem.

Comment: Did you tried `$event.stopPropagation();` ?

Comment: @JBNizet yep missed it, here's stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4hqzwy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fclick-outside.directive.ts

Comment: @NasiruddinSaiyed you want that on `.menu-trigger`? seems to be working https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oqgtjp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Yes its should stop events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid Parent event running you need to stop it from child element, you can do it by

```
$event.stopPropagation();
```

> The `event.stopPropagation()` method stops the bubbling of an event to
>   parent elements, preventing any parent event handlers from being
>   executed.

If you want to learn some basics and advance more **HTML EVENTS** you can check [this](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_eventattributes.asp) out.

Comment: do you know from the perspective of Angular - why it is getting fired when `*ngIf=flase`? I thought if element not in the dom it should not accept any interactions

Comment: It actually is in the DOM in this moment. 1. Page load - not in DOM 2. The click on the trigger sets `showList  = true` --> in the DOM 3. event bubbling 4. triggers host listener 5. `showList  = false` --> not in DOM anymore